# JavaScript DOM depth via recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a node with a bunch of child nodes which recurse. I'm trying to find out how far each node is from the root (which has an id of 'comment-0').

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="comment-0">
  <div id="comment-2598" class="comment comment--parent" data-cid="2598">
    <div id="comment-2599" class="comment comment--child" data-cid="2599">
      <div id="comment-2615" class="comment comment--child" data-cid="2615">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="comment-2604" class="comment comment--child" data-cid="2604">
      <div id="comment-2616" class="comment comment--child" data-cid="2616">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The calling function:

```
rootNode.querySelectorAll('.comment').forEach((el)=>{
  const result = findDepth(el,0);
  console.log("el: "+el.id, result);
});
```

and my recursive function:

```
const findDepth = (el, depth) => {
    depth++;
    console.log(el.id, el.parentNode.id);
    console.log(depth);
    if(el.parentNode.id !== 'comment-0'){
        findDepth(el.parentNode, depth);
    }else {
        return depth;
    }
};
```

The recursive function seems to successfully walk up to find out how far each node is from the root but, regardless the value of `depth` inside the function, when the value is returned it's *undefined* and I can't see why.

Comment: try `return findDepth(...)`? in the `if` statement?

Comment: Recursion isn't needed. You can just use a loop that assigns `el = el.parentNode` until `el.id == 'comment-0'`

Comment: CollinD already supplied the correct answer.  But I think your function can be simplified to: `const findDepth = (el) => el && el.id == 'comment-0' ? 0 : 1 + findDepth (el.parentNode)`.

Comment: @Barmar: but a recursive solution might be the most elegant here.  See my previous comment.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Nice, and you can't forget `return` with that style of arrow function. The tail-recursive version is `findDepth = (el, depth = 0) => el.id == 'comment-0' ? depth : findDepth(el, depth+1);`

Comment: @Barmar: also nice, but there is a danger if you try use `Array.prototype.map` (or `forEach`) with that tail-recursive style.  It usually won't stop me, but I always have to remember to keep it in mind.

Comment: Thanks, ScottSauyet and Barnar; CollinD was spot on, that alone has fixed it (I hadn't twigged that I actually needed that return from the function - every day's a schoolday); I'll have a go at Scott's simplification too - just for future readability.